# Heroku cedar, Rails 3.1rc6, subdomain routing

Tags: routes, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Locally, on Unicorn, my subdomain setup works fine. I've followed the [heroku subdomain docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) to the letter, and also the subdomains [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3).  subdomain.lvh.me:3000 points to the right place, and lvh.me:3000 points correctly to the root defined in routes.rb:

```
  root :to => "pages#home"
```

However, in my new staging deployment on Heroku's Cedar stack, again using Unicorn, whilst subdomain.mydomain.co.uk points to the right place, mydomain.co.uk doesn't. Instead of going to pages#home as per the routes file, it's hitting the books controller, which it's only meant to do if there's a subdomain in the url, as per routes.rb:

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
match '/' => 'books#show'
end
```

My DNS settings are as per the Heroku docs, and the host command returns what the docs say it should. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @Snowangel, I'm glad you solved your issue! You should paste the solution into the Answer box below, remove it from your question, and then mark the answer as 'accepted'. This will help other people find the solution more easily :)

Comment: Thank *you* :) That's worth at least one upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the aliased domain to subdomain.rb:

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www" && request.subdomain != "nameofmydomain" 
  end
end
```