# Rails acts_as_tenant - would like to prevent access to my site without a subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, multi-tenant

The acts_as_tenant gem works really well. No problems saving and retrieving data for multiple tenants. However, I ran into a challenge when I access my dev site without the subdomain.

THE PROBLEM: IF I don't specify a subdomain, users from any tenant can still login.

Example - a user for cheese.lvh.me:3000 would not be able to log into and access data from  bacon.lvh.me:3000 (and vice versa). BUT both cheese and bacon users can log into lvh.me:3000. Once logged in, the tenant scope does not apply anymore so all new inserts get a NULL account_id.

I'D LIKE TO: Prevent user login if subdomain is NOT specified.

I'm using M.Hartl's user login method from the popular railstutorial.org.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) 
    sign_in user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome user!"
    redirect_to users_path
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of would be to wrap the routes you don't want accessed without a subdomain in a subdomain constraint:

```
constraints(SubdomainRequired) do
  # routes go here
end
```

This `SubdomainRequired` constant is best, I think, defined within the `lib/constraints` directory of your application, in a file named after the class (`lib/constraints/subdomain_required.rb`):

```
class SubdomainRequired
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present?
  end
end
```

Then it's simply a matter of requiring this constraint at the top of your routes file:

```
require 'constraints/subdomain_required'
```

If the subdomain is present with this, then the route will be found. If the request is not made with a subdomain then it will not be found.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Even being pretty new to rails, the solution makes perfect sense. I will try this promptly and accept the answer.

Comment: sorry for the late update - I tried this and it works well, thank you!

Comment: When deploying to Heroku, I had to dig just a little more...
These additions were needed to make things work as in the test environment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151837/heroku-cedar-rails-3-1rc6-subdomain-routing)